# how to make a GCM servlet?

Tags: android, eclipse, servlets, google-cloud-messaging

I've been following [this guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#server-app)
and still dont get it (Im quite new to the whole android-stuff, Im sorry).

"1. Create a servlet (or other server-side mechanism) that can be used by the Android application to send the registration ID received by GCM . The application might also need to send other information—such as the user's email address or username—so that the server can associate the registration ID with the user owning the device.
 
2. Similarly, create a servlet used to unregister registration IDs."

I dont think this guide is very thorough overall but right here I ran into some trouble. Is there any kind code-cracker out there who can help me?
How do I make a "servlet" for GCM?
Thank you in advance!
PS. Im using eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably take a look at the [GCM Demo Application](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html) page, specifically the [Setting Up the Server](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html#server-setup) section which shows two methods for setting up a GCM server. I have seen a few other GCM developers using Google App Engine for their GCM servers as detailed in [point two](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html#appengine-setup) of the link.

There are also commercial solutions out there such as [AirBop](http://airbop.com/) (which I happened to help create), [Urban Airship](http://www.urbanairship.com/), and a few others.