# How to create a server for android application

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to android development..I want to send notification from one mobile app to another mobile. I know its done using GCM but how do I create a server for my application??

My application shares task with another user..for eg if the user makes a group of users on my application and add some common task in the group..my application will send notification to all the users in the group!

so what are the steps to create a server for such an application?? 
please help!

Comment: try [Here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/) and [Here](http://www.roman10.net/android-tcp-client-and-server-communication-programmingillustrated-with-example/) it will give a good idea about your Problem.

Comment: Take a look at my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804385/how-to-make-a-gcm-servlet/13806993#13806993 that should help